# Save a local variable on a heap without using malloc in C (using sbrk or brk)

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct 
  __attribute__((__packed__)) // compiler directive, avoid "gcc" padding bytes to struct
  meta_data {
    size_t size;             // 8 bytes (in 64-bit OS)
    char free;               // 1 byte ('f' or 'o')
};
```

The size of the struct is 9 bytes.

I want to use sbrk or brk to allocate 9 bytes on the heap and save a struct on the heap, and return a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory block on heap.

Currently I have something like this:

```
void *add(size_t size) {
  void* returnPointer;
  returnPointer = sbrk(9);
  struct meta_data newMetadata;
  newMetadata.size = size;
  newMetadata.free = 'o';
  return returnPointer;
}
```

This function should be able to be used multiple times to add more metadata blocks on the heap.

However, in this case, when the function ends, the local variable newMetadata declared inside the function is also terminated.

How can I keep it on the heap and not lose access to the newMetadata created?

Note: I am not allowed to use malloc for this.

Comment: Make `newMetadata` a pointer, and make it point to the new memory returned by `sbrk`?

Comment: Only the malloc implementation is allowed to call `sbrk` with a nonzero argument. Unless you are writing a complete malloc implementation, do this with `mmap` instead.

Comment: (If this is a homework assignment, and it's not an assignment to write a complete malloc implementation, and you were specifically told to use `sbrk`, then the assignment is buggy and you may tell your instructor I said so.)

Comment: (Addendum: _no one_ besides `sbrk` itself is allowed to call `brk` at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual method is to mimic what some `malloc` packages do. That is, put the meta data at a lower address than what is returned as the "data" pointer.

Here's your code refactored to do that:

```
#include <unistd.h>

struct meta_data {
    size_t size;                        // 8 bytes (in 64-bit OS)
    char free;                          // 1 byte ('f' or 'o')
// compiler directive, avoid "gcc" padding bytes to struct
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));

void *
add(size_t size)
{
    struct meta_data *meta;
    void *returnPointer;

    meta = sbrk(sizeof(struct meta_data) + size);
    meta->size = size;
    meta->free = 'o';

    returnPointer = meta;
    returnPointer += sizeof(struct meta_data);

    return returnPointer;
}
```

Note that most `malloc` replacements will guarantee that `returnPointer` is "aligned for any purpose", which usually means aligned to an 8 byte boundary (i.e. the lower 3 bits of `returnPointer` are 0).

The above code doesn't do that, so it's something you can add [later].

Comment: `returnPointer += ...` should be avoided as C does not define arithmetic on `void *`, you could do `struct meta_data *returnPointer; returnPointer = meta; returnPointer++; return returnPointer;`.